# Como salvar conteúdo dos data sets em arquivos de forma dinâmica?

Tags: r

Tenho um vetor com o nome dos meus datasets e quero armazenar o conteúdo dos mesmos em arquivos `.csv` individuais de forma dinâmica.

Com o código abaixo, os arquivos são criados, mas ao invés do conteúdo dos data sets, é gravado o nome do data set. já usei o `assign()` e dá na mesma.

```
dsets <- c('wairlines', 'wairports', 'wflights', 'wplanes', 'wweather')

for(ix in 1:length(dsets)) {
  write.csv(dsets[ix], file = paste0('./input_orig/',dsets[ix],'.csv'))
}
```

O código acima deveria ser equivalente a:

```
write.csv(wairlines,file='./input_orig/wairlines.csv')
write.csv(wairports,file='./input_orig/wairports.csv')
write.csv(wflights,file='./input_orig/wflights.csv')
write.csv(wplanes,file='./input_orig/wplanes.csv')
write.csv(wweather,file='./input_orig/wweather.csv')
```

Desde já meu agradecimento

Comment: Obrigado pelo copydesk... aprendendo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dsets` é um vetor de strings, não é uma lista de data.frames.
Para aceder aos data.frames tem que ir buscá-los com `get`.
Além disso, não é necessário compor os nomes dos ficheiros um a um, o `paste` é uma função vetorizada.

```
dsets <- c('wairlines', 'wairports', 'wflights', 'wplanes', 'wweather')
fl <- paste0('./input_orig/', dsets, '.csv')
env <- .GlobalEnv
for(ix in seq_along(dsets)) {
  write.csv(get(dsets[ix], envir = env), file = fl[ix])
}
```

Ou, sem o vetor de nomes de ficheiros `fl`:

```
env <- .GlobalEnv
lapply(dsets, function(x){
  fl <- paste0('./input_orig/', x, '.csv')
  write.csv(get(x, envir = env), file = fl)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Galera, encontrei a solução.... o código correto deveria ser....
dsets <- c('wairlines', 'wairports', 'wflights', 'wplanes', 'wweather')

for(ix in 1:length(dsets)) {
write.csv(***get(dsets[ix])***, file = paste0('./input_orig/',dsets[ix],'.csv'))
}
Esse get() faz toda a diferença e abre uma super-dimensão de automatização de funções..

Comment: Rui... Obrigado... só vi agora... o crédito será dado...